# How to interpolate query string on NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-i18next

I am using the `next/link` to direct to a particular page. The link component looks like this:

```
<Link
    href={{
      pathname: `/users/[slug]?lang=${lang}`,
      query: { slug, lang },
    }}
>
 Click me
</Link>
```

The `lang` is the selected language (i18) of the user.

#### Problem

Every time I reach the page in question, after refreshing I am getting this error:

**`Error: The provided "href" (/users/[slug]?lang=en) value is missing query values (slug) to be interpolated properly. Read more: https://err.sh/vercel/next.js/href-interpolation-failed`**

Yet my URL looks like this `http://localhost:3000/users/Y0901083155?lang=en`
where the slug is **Y0901083155** and the lang is **en**

#### Pages architecture

```
├──_app.js
├──index.js
├──user/ --------------> folder
   ├──[slug]/ --------> folder
      ├── edit/    ----> folder
      ├── create/  ----> folder
      ├── index.tsx
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should include the `slug` in the pathname and pass `lang` in the query object.

```js
// Assuming slug='some-slug', and lang='en'

<Link
    href={{
        pathname: `/users/${slug}`, // Will match `/users/some-slug` path
        query: { lang } // Will pass `?lang=en` as query param
    }}
>
    Click me
</Link>
```

Comment: This solution is not working for me. I'm still getting the same error

Comment: I have seen your code sandbox. I realized that my page's architecture is different from yours. Let me update my question with my architecture

Comment: Even with your folder structure, my solution still works. I've updated the codesandbox to reflect your structure.

Comment: yeah, I have seen it. I really don't what's wrong with my code. thank you anyway for helping me out

Comment: If you could provide a repo/codesandbox with the issue, I'd be happy to go through it and help. Good luck!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228233/discussion-between-coolbeatz71-and-juliomalves).